# PigDice java error

Tags: java

Ok so i have to code a program pig dice and i have most of it done and running but the biggest problem is that the score isnt adding and i really need help with it, it uses the face value from a separate program Die which are randomly generated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pigDiceGame
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    // This section will ask the user is they know how to play the game of                      Pig Dice

    System.out.println("You are Going to Play the Pig Dice Game!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Do You Know the rules?...if not press 1...otherwise   press any key to continue.");

    // This sectionwill allow the user to input whether they want to read   the rules or not
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int rules = scanner.nextInt ();

    // This sectionwill actually explain the rules of the game
    if (rules == 1)
    {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Rules...");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1. In one turn the player rolls the dice until   either");
    System.out.println("    -They roll a one");
    System.out.println("    -Or they choose to stop");
    System.out.println("2. You add up the numbers on the dice and are trying                                                   to reach 100.");
    System.out.println("3. Rolling a 1 will clear your points for that turn.");
    System.out.println("4. If you choose to stop you can keep the points you have earned.");
    System.out.println("5. Rolling a pair counts double points");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("Lets begin...");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");



    // all the variables I am using in the game are here

    int roll=1;


    while (roll<=1)
    {
    System.out.println("Player-one roll,enter 1 to role or 2 to save");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    roll = scanner.nextInt ();


    if(roll==1)
    {
    if(roll==1)
    roll=roll-1;


    Die c = new Die();
    Die d = new Die();
    int faceValue1=c.roll();
    int faceValue2=d.roll();



    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("You rolled a:: "+faceValue1);
    System.out.print(" and "+faceValue2);
    System.out.println();
    int score=faceValue1+faceValue2;

    if(faceValue1==1||faceValue2==1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled a one, your score has been set to zero,unless you banked some points and your turn is over.");
    roll=3;
    System.out.println();
    }
    else
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score);
    System.out.println();

    if(faceValue1==1&&faceValue2==1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled two ones, that adds 25 points to your score.");
    score=score+25;
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score);
    System.out.println();
    }

    if(faceValue1==faceValue2&&faceValue1!=1&&faceValue2!=1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled doubles, that is double the points.");
    score=(faceValue1+faceValue2)*2;
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score);
    System.out.println();
    }


    if(score==100)
    {
    System.out.println("Player-One WINS!");
    roll=9;

    }




      }


   }


    while (roll==3)
    {
    int score2=0;


    System.out.println("Player-Two roll,enter 3 to role or 4 to save");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    roll = scanner.nextInt ();




    Die c = new Die();
    Die d = new Die();
    int faceValue1=c.roll();
    int faceValue2=d.roll();
    int score=0;


    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("You rolled a:: "+faceValue1);
    System.out.print(" and "+faceValue2);
    System.out.println();
    score2=faceValue1+faceValue2;

    if(faceValue1==1||faceValue2==1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled a one, your score has been set to zero,unless you banked some points and your turn is over.");
    score2=score-score;
    roll=1;

    }
    else
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score2);
    System.out.println();

    if(faceValue1==1&&faceValue2==1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled two ones, that adds 25 points to your score.");
    score2=score2+25;
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score2);
    System.out.println();
    }
    if(faceValue1==faceValue2&&faceValue1!=1&&faceValue2!=1)
    {
    System.out.println("You rolled doubles, that is double the points.");
    score2=(faceValue1+faceValue2)*2;
    System.out.println("Current score is "+score2);
    System.out.println();
    }

    if(score==100)
    System.out.println("Player-Two WINS!");
    roll=9;


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you enhance your question with the output it generates, what you expect and where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring your variable later on. You only need to instantiate each variable once, otherwise it's being set to 0.

```
int score=faceValue1+faceValue2; // (line 71)
int score=0; // (line 132)
```

It will likely be much easier for you to manage and see what's going on if you declare all of your variables at the very top of your functions and methods.